# Torch MPS on Intel Mac: get name of device?

Tags: python, gpu, torch, mps

In Python, on a machine that has an NVIDIA GPU, one can confirm the mps device name of the GPU using:

`torch.cuda.get_device_name()`

Per the docs: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.get_device_name.html#torch.cuda.get_device_name

How do I confirm the mps device name for an Intel-based Mac, which has an AMD GPU? I don't see any mention of that in the docs.

Comment: Pertinent: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-support-for-intel-gpus-on-mac/151996 -- MPS should work on AMD GPUs, same as it does on the M1 part, it's deliberately disabled on Intel ones.

Comment: Are you sure it's disabled on Intel macs? According to Apple, Pytorch-Metal acceleration using GPUs is enabled for:

`Mac computers with Apple silicon or AMD GPUs`.

My Intel Macbook Pro has an AMD GPU

https://developer.apple.com/metal/pytorch/

Comment: Intel _GPUs_ is what I was referring to, not Intel _Macs_; thought saying it "should work on AMD GPUs" would make that clear, since M1s don't support external GPUs..

Comment: Ahh, I misread "it's disabled on Intel ones"